# Deployment of PHP project with Hudson/Jenkins

Tags: php, deployment, build, hudson, jenkins

Currently I deploy my PHP project using Subversion checkout on the target machine. I use Hudson/Jenkins for testing and code analysis purposes, but **can** and **should** it be used for deployment? If so, how?

Comment: *(tip)* http://edorian.posterous.com/setting-up-jenkins-for-php-projects

Comment: I think @arex1337 isn't asking for "how to install jenkins" but "how to / should i use jenkins to get my code to the production servers". Can you clarify ? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use it for all the above where I work. I've briefly described the process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012093/separate-building-from-deployment-with-hudson). You can Google ["Hudson template"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Hudson%20template) or ["Jenkins template"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Jenkins%20template) for a boilerplate to doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently researching Jenkins for use with PHP-based projects, but have yet to use it in an actual deployment situation. Chapter 12 of *Jenkins: The Definitive Guide* by John Ferguson Smart covers implementing automated and continuous deployment.  This chapter should give you some ideas.  You can download the guide for 'free' from

http://www.wakaleo.com/books/jenkins-the-definitive-guide

...provided you're willing to fill out your details in the download form.

Also, Sebastian Bergmann (the creator of the [php-template for Jenkins](http://jenkins-php.org/)) has authored a book entitled *Integrate Your PHP Project with Jenkins* which is supposed to be published in August, 2011 by O'Reilly Media.  I don't know the exact contents of the book, but let's hope it provides good examples of how to use Jenkins for deploying applications built using PHP.

Comment: Addendum: The first part of a multi-part tutorial by J. Armando Jeronymo on continuous integration with Jenkins has just appeared on PHPmaster: http://phpmaster.com/continuous-integration-with-jenkins-1/ Hopefully the next parts in the tutorial series will discuss what kinds of development scenarios benefit most from using Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

you should check out the build pipeline plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin
you can set up your own qa workflow with that.