# how to build just svn changed files in jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have installed Subversion and Jenkins to set a CI practice but I have some issues :
- How can I see the subversion changes in jenkins platform and have the choice between changes and build just what I agree with
- I use "Publish Over FTP" plugin with jenkins and I send files by FTP after builds, but all the files are sent, how can I send just changed files (add, edit, delete changed ones)??

Answer (score 0):

You have actually two questions here. Let's try to answer them together.

> How can I see the subversion changes in jenkins platform and have the
>   choice between changes and build just what I agree with

You use tagging for this. Tagging helps you to get a specific version without needing to use revision numbers. As a rule of thumb every version that is given out for testing should have a tag. Some will disagree on the term 'every version'. At least releases need to be tagged. When you follow this philosophy you can use the 'list subversion parameter' to list all the available tags and you can choose the one you like to build.

> I use "Publish Over FTP" plugin with jenkins and I send files by FTP
>   after builds, but all the files are sent, how can I send just changed
>   files (add, edit, delete changed ones)??

Checked the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+FTP+Plugin#PublishOverFTPPlugin-configuration) and in the advanced transfer sets settings it shows how to use file masks to define the files to be transferred. It also contains an exclusion option that you can use to eliminate certain files.

DISCLAIMER: I heavily use the list subversion parameter (which comes with the subversion plugin) and i am happy with it. I don't use the "Publish over FTP plugin" but scanned over the documentation.